# Novel about immortality being kept secret by world leaders

Tags: story-identification, novel, immortality

I read this novel around 1985-1990. It was written in French, I cannot tell if it is the original language or a translation.

The story occurs throughout the whole 20th century.

In this novel the world leaders (like JFK, etc.) secretly meet to talk about a big threat that must remain secret. This threat turns out to be immortality.

As far as I remember, the author has put the history in real historical context, i.e. those meetings actually occurred.

Comment: Any idea when you read this? There are a bunch of other things you could try adding, see [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for a list of prompts.

Comment: My first thought is 'The trouble with lichen' by John Wyndham

Comment: @DannyMcG There are indeed some common points with my novel, but it's not that one. Thank you for the attempt.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you're talking about **Le Grand Secret** by René Barjavel (originally published in the early 70s).

The English translation is called **The Immortals**.

An Indian character discovers a virus that causes immortality. He tells Indian Prime Minister Nehru, who then alerts other world leaders.

It was adapted into a (French language) TV miniseries in 1989.